# Ryzen 9 Temperature Jumps

Tags: windows-10, cpu, temperature

I recently build a new PC with a Ryzen 9 3900x.
I noticed variations in CPU Fan Speed and when looking at HWMonitor i noticed temperature jumps of around 10-15 degrees even under next to no load, which causes the Fan to ramp up. The temperature then reduces really quickly to the one it was sitting at before.

At first it seemed like the Windows 10 "Energy Save" (german Energiesparmodus) power mode helped, but it still does it, but more rarely.

My Setup:

- Gigabyte Aorus Ultra X570
- Ryzen 9 3900X
- AMD Wraith Prism Cooler
- Fractal Design R6 with a PWM Module (Cpu Fan is connected to it)

My question is: What causes these jumps and do i have to tolerate them or is there something i can do?

Comment: Your CPU is capable of boosting its frequency, this raises the temperature slightly, thus causing the fan to turn on.  This fear is unrelated to cpu usage

Comment: Are you perhaps looking at core temperatures? CPU core temperature can change extremely quickly. You may not even see the load that caused them. However, that’s not usually what the fan controller is working with.

Comment: But the Fan is ramping up exactly at those temperature jumps, so even if it's the core temperature it's still causing my CPU cooler to increase RPM rapidly. And shortly after it's back to normal.

Comment: You have a stock fan, while it was designed to cool the processor within the design specifications, it's not as efficient at doing that as an after market cooling solution.  **What you describe is normal.**

Comment: Unefficient or not as good cooling might be normal. But a temperature sensor jumping 10 -15degrees at once, rather than increasing gradually does'nt sound normal to me. And when changing settings inside windows influence the frequency of these jumps it propably isn't the fan's fault. Also the Wraith Prism is much more potent than most other stock fans.